# Unix time uncertainty

Tags: unix, time, utc

I have a gap in Unix time understanding. Unix time started to be counted on 1/1/1970 but in what timezone?
Say it´s 31st of December 1969 11p.m. in London (-3600 Unix time)
In Sidney they have 8 a.m. 1st of January 1970 (28 800 Unix time) in the same time.
So my question is when did they start counting Unix time? 1/1 1970 of what timezone?

Thank you

Comment: I guess they are using UTC as "parent" timezone. At the moment unix time "started" it wasn't the 1/1/1970 all over the world - which is in fact even today impossible ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unix time" should always be UTC.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

Wikipedia has some further verbiage around this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#UTC_basis:

> The precise definition of Unix time as an encoding of UTC is only
>   uncontroversial when applied to the present form of UTC. Fortunately,
>   the fact that the Unix epoch predates the start of this form of UTC
>   does not affect its use in this era: the number of days from 1 January
>   1970 (the Unix epoch) to 1 January 1972 (the start of UTC) is not in
>   question, and the number of days is all that is significant to Unix
>   time.

Comment: Thank you ziesemer!

Comment: Additional question, If I do 'echo time();' it will take into account my timezone. Let' s say I have a friend in New York (different time zone) and he wants me to convert 8am his time. Should I first do '(date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York")' and then 'time()'?

Comment: Judging by `date_default_timezone_set`, it sounds like you're working with PHP - which ideally should have been noted here and the question tagged as such.  (Was going to say, `echo time();` isn't valid at a bash prompt.)  PHP "time" is "Unix time", though.  `date +%s` currently returns `1472564389` - which converts to `2016-08-30 13:39:49 UTC`.  If I run this on multiple servers across the globe, regardless of what their time zone is set to, it will return the same value.  Unix time is independent of time zone - so setting the time zone to New York or otherwise should result in no change.